# How to convert json formated java string to json object in controller

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring-mvc

All examples of converting string to json are of javascript. mine is java class. So, i have a simple java string but formated in json. now i have recieved that from jquery post. now i have to convert that string into json object so that i can access the specific fields.

**controller class**

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
    public void storeData(@RequestParam(value = "temp_str", required = false) String j_str, HttpServletRequest request) {


               // do the conversion and extraction of data from "j_str"


            }
```

**j_str variable is recieveing this string**

> {"temp_data":[{"temp_email":"roykumarsuraj@gmail.com","temp_pwd":"abc123"}]}

Answer (score 0):

http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            Person p = gson.fromJson("your json string", Person.class);
            System.out.println(p);
```

you can use that libary to manage json objectos its very cool
the Person.class is a java bean must have all properties you have in your string

Comment: ok...i got --- pojo.pojo@243ea18b ,,, now how to extract data from it..

Comment: ahh, well, you can override method toString, or you can get a property for example:  System.out.println( "My Name is: " + p.getName()); 

  if your pojo is null is because your string is not matching the json format is required by the pojo

the first response means your pojo object was parsed from json to Object

Answer (score 0):

If your Json string is extremely simple, you can just use:

```
JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject(j_str);
```

Now you can access the JSON elements by:

```
JSONArray jarr=jobj.getJSONArray('temp_data');
JSONObject jarr1=jarr.get(0);  // will contain {"temp_email":"roykumarsuraj@gmail.com","temp_pwd":"abc123"}
```

Now you can further access jarr1 similar to jobj.

Comment: it gives error,, syntax error,,, cant convert j_str to jobj,, my json string is posted in my question body.

Comment: can you post the exact wording of the error? and print the j_str to see if it resembles what's in your question body.

Comment: constructor JSONObject is class JSONObject cannot be applied to given types;

Comment: Modify your import statement to 'import org.json.JSONArray;import org.json.JSONObject; '